# Eloquent Relation with foreign key

Tags: eloquent, foreign-keys, relationship, laravel-5.6

I have issues by connecting to tables

I have 2 Model

First Model called **PodioBorgerNotat** with columns in the table called **podio_borger_notats**

- id
- user_id
- item_id
- app_item_id
- borger_item_id (foreign key)
- medarbejder_item_id
- status

The second Model called **PodioBorgerStamark** with columns in the table **podio_borger_stamarks**

- id
- item_id (local key)
- app_item_id
- status
- initials
- name

I want to make a connection between **PodioBorgerNotat** and **PodioBorgerStamark**

so this is what I do in **PodioBorgerNotat** **Model**

```
public function borger()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(PodioBorgerStamark::class, 'borger_item_id', 'item_id');
    }
```

Now I want to output the result by executing this output

```
$borgernotater = PodioBorgerNotat::orderBy('created_at', 'acs')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->with('PodioBorgerStamark')->paginate(10);
```

This wont work and i get this error messsage

```
Call to undefined relationship [PodioBorgerStamark] on model [App\PodioBorgerNotat].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relation name is `borger`:

```
public function borger(){ 
    ... 
}
```

You should call `borger` in `with()`:

```
$borgernotater = PodioBorgerNotat
    ::orderBy('created_at', 'acs')
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->with('borger')
    ->paginate(10);
```